# Creeping thyme as lawn cover for large lawns?

Tags: lawn, ground-cover

I've read some articles on how creeping thyme can be used as lawn-cover instead of grass. It all sounds too good to be true. (No mowing, stays green even during dry times, blocks out other weeds...etc) I have around 4 acres of grass behind my home in NW Ohio. Does anyone have experience planting creeping thyme, and if so, any thoughts on whether this is actually viable, or just an online fad?

My lawn butts up against a few neighbors lawns. Will it eventually encroach and take over their lawns?

Answer (score 1):

What will happen is that grass and other windblown seeds will arrive and you will end up with a mixed species lawn. Thyme and grass can coexist but you end up mowing it.